# Boot - Failed to Load ldlinux.c32

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I'm trying to run Ubuntu off of a USB. The exact error message read as follows:

`SYSLINUX 6.03 EDD 2014-10-06 Copyright (C) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al`

`Failed to load ldlinux.c32
Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue.`

I used a brand-new 32GB USB 3.0 from HP (Hewlett Packard). I installed it using a Windows 7 Computer (BIOS), which was unable to boot it from the USB. I tried booting it on a Ubuntu 13.04 Lenovo laptop (BIOS) with the same result. I was using the latest LTS ISO from lubuntu.com `(lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386)`.

I tried writing in the ISO image mode multiple times with the same result before trying the DD image mode, which threw a "corrupt file" error and then wiped the USB entirely blank, so I slow-formatted it in FAT32 on my next attempt (instead of the instruction's usual "quick format" option).

I'm totally lost! Here I was, trying to learn Linux, and I'm unable to even boot it! Help, please?

EDIT = The ubuntu laptop I used for the experiment was my brother's laptop